# Failover - azure. Connection string

Tags: azure-sql-database, failover, connection-string

I've got a primary and secondary database that i've just configured a Failover group.

My question is:
Can existing connection still connect directly to the DB, or do i need to change all connection strings to my application?
or is it just a  "declarative abstraction" architecture on top of the active geo-replication currently used?

Many thanks

Current architecture
[image]

Failover architecture
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey, I am asking if the connection string for the app will change also if i am configuring Failover? And how will it affect existing connection application? Does this involve any downtime?